# in yii2 on using TCPDF library i am getting "Failed to load PDF document." error

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, tcpdf

I am trying to generate example pdf file as it is shown here: https://packagist.org/packages/hbalkhi/yii2-pdf.

output --->
[this is the out put.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqsd.png)

**myController**

```
public function actionTcpdf()
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type','application/pdf');

        return $this->render('tcpdf');
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php

/**
 * @copyright Copyright &copy;2014 Giandomenico Olini
 * @company Gogodigital - Wide ICT Solutions 
 * @website http://www.gogodigital.it
 * @package yii2-tcpdf
 * @github https://github.com/cinghie/yii2-tcpdf
 * @license GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE VERSION 3
 * @tcpdf library 6.0.075
 * @tcpdf documentation http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php
 * @tcpdf examples http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php
 */
// echo "12345";
// exit();

// Load Component Yii2 TCPDF 
\Yii::$app->get('tcpdf');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Gogogital.it');
$pdf->SetTitle('Yii2 TCPDF Example');
$pdf->SetSubject('Yii2 TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, 'Yii2 TCPDF Example', 'Gogodigital - Wide ICT Solutions | gogodigital.it', array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print
$html = "<h1>Yii2 TCPDF Works Fine!</h1>";

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('yii2_tcpdf_example.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+

// Close Yii2
\Yii::$app->end();

?>
```

this is the view code. I have been echoing at different places and it works fine but when i echo in view where m making a new variable for pdf in start the echo doesn't comes but the error.

Comment: Are you sure your temporary directory has full read/write privileges?

Comment: where would i get to check these privileges?

Comment: If you have root access you can check it directly on the file system. Usually it's /tmp or /var/tmp on linux systems. You can check the output of phpinfo() to see where your tmp directory is located.

Comment: but the issue is in view, i echo at different places to see where the issue is so it when i echo at view after the line " $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); " the echo doesn't come but that error.

Comment: $pdf->Output('myfilename.pdf', 'I'); will output the pdf to the browser from the controller, which is what I'm using and it works fine.

Comment: i do have this line in my code.
but still i don't get the output

Comment: see i have edited the post and put the view code aswell.

Comment: in console this error is shown " Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Failed to instantiate component or class "hbalkhi\tcpdf\TCPDF".' 
 "

Comment: do you have configured the component in your config file?

Comment: 'component' => [ 
...
  'tcpdf' => [
   'class' => 'hbalkhi\tcpdf\TCPDF',
  ],
  ...
]

Comment: yes i did. i folowed every step